# Evaluate the integral $\int_C \frac{1}{z^3} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Where $C$ is the square centered in the origin with edges in $-1+i$, $-1-i$, $1+i$ and $1-i$.

The first step I made is $$\displaystyle \int_C \frac{1}{z^3} dz = \int_C \frac{\frac{1}{z^2}}{z} dz$$

But the problem is on how could I apply the Cauchy's Integral Formula. Any help?

And using the same $C$ as above, how would it work for $\displaystyle \int_C \frac{sin(z)}{z^4}dz$? If it's possible, just a hint.

I saw a few examples here, but I still do not understand the process to solve this kind of integrals.

Comment: What is $sen(z)$? is it $\sin(z)$?

Comment: My mistake, it was written in spanish. I already corrected it. Yes, it's sin(z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the region enclosed in the square, the integrand function has one pole $z =0$. By residue theorem $$\int_C \frac{1}{z^3}dz = 2\pi i \operatorname{res}_{z=0}\frac{1}{z^3} = 0$$, i.e. the integral is zero.

Comment: For every simple curve enclosing the origin, the integral is $2\pi i \cdot Res(f(z), z_0 = 0)$. So, are we treating this square as a simple curve? Or, as @Reveillark said, as the unitary circle?

Comment: Yes, the square is a simple curve and we can apply residue theorem. You can apply the theorem on unit circle since there is no pole other than $0$ so integral value on the square and the circle is the same.

Comment: For the situation of $\sin(z)/z^4$, everythings are almost same, but you have to find the residue of $\sin(z) /z^4$ at $z=0$. There is no pole other than $z=0$

Comment: I know three types of singularities; removable, pole, and essential. I don't know what is evitable sigularities. Anyway it is pole, with order higher than $1$, so residue is 0.

Comment: Okay, now I see why it is $0$. Because it's a thirth order pole, so $Res(\frac{1}{z^3}, 0) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{2!} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}[z^3 \cdot \frac{1}{z^3}] = 0$

Comment: And for $sin(z)/z^4$ I found that the residue is $i\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: check 2\pi i term and the sign again.

Comment: My bad. It's $-i \frac{\pi}{3} $

Answer (score 2):

Since the square is homotopic to the boundary of the unit disk $D$, we have that
$$
\int_C \frac{1}{z^3}dz=\int_{\partial D} \frac{1}{z^3}dz
$$
Now use the parametrization $\theta\mapsto e^{i\theta}$, with $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$.